# How to prevent quote signs in File.readlines

Tags: ruby, string, file

For example I have file `file_name` with such content:

```
Just some text,
nothing more
```

Then I run kind of this code:

```
lines = File.open(file_name, "r").readlines
# do something do with lines
File.open(file_name, "w").write(lines)
```

I'll get this text

```
"Just some text,"
"nothing more"
```

How to prevent `"` sign here? I want text without quotes. Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be getting those.  Are you sure that something in your "do something with lines" block isn't adding the quotes?  If you run your program just as you quoted, do you get the quotes?  (I don't.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using ruby 1.9.2, `Array#to_s` works like `Array#inspect`.  Try this instead (some style tweaks thrown in):

```rb
lines = File.readlines(file_name)
File.open(file_name, 'w') { |f| f.write(lines.join) }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `lines.join("\n")`?

Comment: No, because the lines read by readlines include line-endings,

Answer (score 1):

If you are only concerned with the quotes enclosing each line

okay, let's try that again

```
lines.gsub(/^"|"$/, '')
```

should work